# How do I clean everything in lua stack from C++?

Tags: c++, lua

Although I fixed the bug by call as less time `lua_getglobal` as I can, it's not good enough for long term. So does anyone know how do I clean everything in lua's stack to prevent memory management problems?

---EDIT---
From the experiments i just did, `lua_settop` will clean up the table to the given value. However, in the time i know how many items are there i want to remove, is `lua_pop` more efficient?

Comment: lua_pop is a macro around lua_settop. See http://www.lua.org/source/5.1/lua.h.html#lua_pop

Comment: @Etan Reisner i got it, so lua_settop is actually more efficient since i'm cleaning everything

Comment: They are equally efficient. They are the same function. lua_pop is a macro, resolved at pre-processing time, around lua_settop. The running code only ever calls lua_settop. (Technically it looks like lua_pop is slightly more efficient since the code does less work in lua_settop that way but I don't believe that is likely to matter in practice.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A simple [`lua_settop(L, 0);`](http://pgl.yoyo.org/luai/i/lua_settop) should do the trick.

A simple, albeit contrive, example say you have a `lua_CFunction`:

```
int foo(lua_State *L)
{
  // marshal some random data
  int bar = luaL_checknumber(L, 1);
  const char *baz = luaL_checkstring(L, 2);
  // do foo's task

  // completely clear the stack before return
  lua_settop(L, 0);
  return 0;
}
```

This is contrived because if `foo` is called by the VM then cleanup is not necessary. But if you have C++ code calling `foo` directly this may be necessary. At any rate hopefully this illustrates its calling context.

Comment: Thank you very much, that helped a lot! Now my game should run more efficiently then before（yeah, i used Lua for 2 months and never noticed there is memory problem just till today）

Comment: np. As a side-note you can also use `lua_settop` to limit the number of arguments the function accepts by doing `lua_settop(L, n);` at the top. So if the user passes in more arguments they're simply ignored and the VM is free to gc it. This can help with api misuse.

Comment: While true, the settop/argument claim, I'm not sure I think that'll help unless you have an extended C-side set of functions calling one another before returning to lua.